# Need divs to be responsive and stack

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a site I'm working on and I have 3 social media feeds lined up horizontally. I need them to stack when viewed on mobile. At the moment they still just appear next to each other horizontally.

Here is the standard layout - goo.gl/4UwsuS

The social media feeds are just a bit further down in the 'about us' section. They are currently set up exactly how I want them to look on a PC but when viewed on a mobile/tablet, I need them to stack vertically on top of each other.

The WordPress theme only allows custom HTML so I've set them up as divs.

Comment: your divs are using absolute positioning and displayed using block. Use relative positioning and inline-block.

Comment: very bad coded with html/css. instead trying to make that part responsive, I suggest you to rebuild that part( it will take max 15-20min, but you'll get content, which you can change/edit/make responsive )

Answer (score 0):

you need a media query that sets the flex container div to either

```
flex-direction:column
```

or

```
flex-wrap:wrap
```

But it will totally break as your layout is not really relating the icons to the feeds...

Might be better to rethink that part: Restucture to make the div inheritance logical, like:

```
-feeds container
--- facebook container
------facebook icon
------facebook feed
--- twitter container
------twitter icon
------facebook feed
--- instagram container
------instagram icon
------instagram feed
```

That way you can set the main feeds container to display flex, with flex-direction row (default) justify-content: space around to create the side-by-side layout, and each media container to display flex but this time flex-direction column and justify-content flex-start in order to keep the icons and feeds aligned as they should.

Then you can use a media query to set the flex-direction of the main feeds container to column whenever you reach the break point.